# How can fixed this problem related with GEM5 , benchmark Parsec

Tags: gem5

sudo scons FULL_SYSTEM=1 build/ALPHA/gem5.opt RUBY=true PROTOCOL=MOESI_CMP_directory
build/ALPHA/gem5.opt configs/example/fs.py --cpu-type=timing \ --script=run_scripts/blackscholes_4c_simsmall.rcS \ --num-cpus=4 --ruby --mesh-rows=2 --garnet=fixed --topology=Mesh \ --caches --l2cache --l2_size=512kB --num-dirs=4 --num-l2=4 \ --l1d_size=32kB --l1i_size=32kB --l1d_assoc=2 --l1i_assoc=2 \ --kernel=/home/fur/gem5/full_system_images_ALPHA/binaries/vmlinux_2.6.27-gcc_4.3.4 \ --disk-image=/home/fur/gem5/full_system_images_ALPHA/disks/linux-parsec-2-1-m5-withtest-inputs.img
it  gave my error: 'fixed' invalid value !!!
please how can fixed that?

GEM5, Parsec benchmark, ruby network